In e91 protocol, if one of the bases combination was not chosen, what should be done to avoid division by zero?
In e91 protocol, if one of the bases combination was not chosen, what should be done in this case to avoid division by zero?
One solution that comes to mind is setting the whole value to zero, but is this solution theoretically correct?
An example of the code is this:
  sum00 = sum(A0B0)
  sum02 = sum(A0B2)
  sum20 = sum(A2B0)
  sum22 = sum(A2B2)

  expect00 = (A0B0[0] - A0B0[1] - A0B0[2] + A0B0[3])/sum00 if sum00!=0 else 0
  expect02 = (A0B2[0] - A0B2[1] - A0B2[2] + A0B2[3])/sum02 if sum02!=0 else 0
  expect20 = (A2B0[0] - A2B0[1] - A2B0[2] + A2B0[3])/sum20 if sum20!=0 else 0
  expect22 = (A2B2[0] - A2B2[1] - A2B2[2] + A2B2[3])/sum22 if sum22!=0 else 0

  corr = expect00 - expect02 + expect20 + expect22

I am aware that for sufficiently large number of bits that situation will not areis, but I am asking more from a theoritical point of view?

The question boils down to how you should infer probabilities from relative frequencies, and that is a hotly disputed subject. Usually this is swept under the carpet by assuming that the number of measurements is so high that one can pretend that the probabilities are just equal to the relative frequencies.
From a Bayesian point of view, the correct way to do inference is to have a prior distribution, and to update it with your data. In your case, you would have for each setting some prior $\{p(++), p(+-), p(-+), p(--)\}$, which you after Bayesian updating gives you some probability distribution conditioned on your data.
Now if you have zero measurements then the updated distribution will just be your prior itself. If your prior is uniform, then the updated expectation value will indeed be zero. Note, however, that this is inconsistent with inferring the expectation value by the formula you gave, as that is not Bayesian updating.

Can you clarify the anwer more? What is my prior distribution and how would I obtain it?

The prior distribution encodes your information before you do any measurements. You just need to choose a reasonable one, there's no universal correct choice. I'm afraid it's too much for me to explain here, you need to learn Bayesian inference to understand it.
